# Matching and replacing a string in XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am not an XSL expert. I need to match a string and replace it with URL. String should be of a form 2 letters + 8 digits, so something like VA12345678.

Here is what I have so far (I have XSL and HTML in the same file):

```
<xsl:variable name="fubar" select="'testing VA12345678'" />

  <xsl:variable name="fubarNew">
    <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="in" select="$fubar" />
      <xsl:with-param name="old" select="'regex will go here'" />
      <xsl:with-param name="new" select="'<a href='/cs/page.asp?id=VA12345678'>VA12345678</a>" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>


<span><xsl:value-of select="$fubarNew" /></span>
```

fubarNew should look like `testing VA12345678` with VA12345678 linked to `/cs/page.asp?id=VA12345678`.

How do I add regex in here?

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to accomplish; especially with that "new" param that's passing a string that just looks like markup. Maybe try using xsl:analyze-string instead: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBHg

Comment: Thanks! my html and xsl stylesheet are all in one file (no option to split this legacy code). I have a variable coming from the database, it's not in the separate xml file, like in the fiddle above. How do I merge the two?

Comment: In other words, is it possible to pass a variable to analyze-string? In this case this variable passed would look like testing VA12345678

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very unclear.

If - as it seems - you want to replace every occurrence of a string in the form of `@@########` (2 upper-case ASCII characters followed by 8 digits) with an anchor element in the form of `<a href="/cs/page.asp?id=@@########">@@########</a>`, then consider the following example:

**Input**

```
<root>
    <string>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer ABC123 adipiscing elit.</string>
    <string>Nam interdum ante quis VA12345678 erat pellentesque elementum. Ut molestie quam sit DT87654321 amet ligula.</string>
    <string>In enim. XY55551234 Duis dapibus hendrerit quam.</string>
</root>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="string">
    <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="[A-Z]{{2}}\d{{8}}" >
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <a href="/cs/page.asp?id={.}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </a>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:non-matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <string>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer ABC123 adipiscing elit.</string>
   <string>Nam interdum ante quis <a href="/cs/page.asp?id=VA12345678">VA12345678</a> erat pellentesque elementum. Ut molestie quam sit <a href="/cs/page.asp?id=DT87654321">DT87654321</a> amet ligula.</string>
   <string>In enim. <a href="/cs/page.asp?id=XY55551234">XY55551234</a> Duis dapibus hendrerit quam.</string>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I don't have xml as input, I have database results and it's not clear how to merge this traditional format (sheet file and xml) into what I have. I am resorting to doing this in the stored procedure.

Comment: If you are using XSLT 2.0, then I believe you do have XML as the input. You can see what it looks like by applying the identity transform.

Comment: we are using XSL 1.0 and it seems more work to convert at this point.

Comment: If you are using XSLT 1.0, then why is your question tagged as `xslt-2.0`??? Also, if you are using XSLT 1.0, then your input **must** be XML.